# Is there any way to find a specific word in OCR result

Tags: python, ocr, paddleocr

I am using paddleocr. I want to find a word/words in the OCR Result.
For example the ocr output is "ilovepythonalot"
And I want to find the word "love" using

```
if Chose1 in ocrresult: #Chose1='love'
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

the result is only giving out "false"
Is there any way that i can fix it?

Comment: You don't really need the `if` statement, instead `print(Chose1 in ocrresult)` unless you specifically need the strings 'true' or 'false' printed as opposed to booleans.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, `paddleocr` likely outputs a list of strings, so you might want to merge them into one text first:

```
if Chose1 in ' '.join(ocrresult): #Chose1='love'
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```